# json.loads appends 'L' to an integer. Is there anyway to avoid it

Tags: python, json

The below Code when executed appends 'L' to the integer, is there any ways to avoid it?

```
>>> import json
>>> d='{"id":1092381230129831120398213}'
>>> print(json.loads(d))
{u'id': 1092381230129831120398213L}
```

Comment: Nice one, jonrsharpe!

Comment: Use python3, but why it's a problem ?